# How to avoid events on elements behind others in HTML and JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with some div's inside it.

I want an event to happen when I click on a td element, but I also want an event to happen when I click on a div element.
As you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rkGkp/1/ my problem is, when I click on the div element, both the div and td event is triggered, but I only want the div's event to be triggered.

I use these event listeners

```
$(function() {
    $("#div").on("click", function() {
        alert("a div is clicked");
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".td").on("click", function() {
        alert("a td is clicked");
    });
});
```

What can I do to avoid the element behind my div to trigger an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkGkp/2/)

I used `stopPropagation()`

**CODE**

```
$("#div").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("a div is clicked");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see it is the same they do here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way to achieve what you need. Simply check if the click target is on the div:

```
$(function() {
   $("#div").on("click", function() {
       alert("a div is clicked");
   });
});
$(function() {
   $(".td").on("click", function(e) {
      if(!$(e.target).is("#div")){
        alert("a td is clicked");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: May as well just do `$('.td').on("click", ":not(#div)", fn)` if you wanted to do it that way